# Adjusting for too many variables

Tags: adjustment

Suppose that you have a linear regression model with outcome variable $Y$ and explanatory variables $X_{1}, \dots, X_{10}$. Suppose $X_1$ is the main effect. Also suppose $X_{2}, \dots, X_{10}$ are associated with the outcome and the explanatory variable based on subject matter expertise. Should you include all the variables $X_{2}, \dots , X_{10}$ in the adjusted model?

Comment: What do you mean by "$X_1$ is the main effect"?

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe: $X_1$ is the effect we care about most.

Comment: Please explain to us how this question differs from your previous one at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89476/including-confounders-in-a-model, apart from the change in variable count from $4$ to $10$.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, the quick answer is yes, you should include any independent variable that is related to the outcome. One of the assumptions of linear regression is that all important predictors have been included in the model (and that the functional form of their relationship with the outcome is correctly specified). If you don't, your residuals are likely not independent from the predictors that you did include, and some regression coefficients and standard errors might be biased (Cohen, Cohen, West, & Aiken, 2003).

Reference:

- Cohen, J., Cohen, P., West, S. G., & Aiken, L. S. (2003). *Applied multiple regression/correlation analysis for the behavioral sciences* (3rd ed.). New York: Routledge.

Comment: Would this apply to survival analysis as well?

Comment: I don't know too much about survival analysis. If you look on this site or on Google for "survival analysis assumptions", that could get you in the right direction.