# Interpretation of a regression result

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data

Hi I have a slight problem understanding something

Variable X is a 0/1 dummy 
Where 1 = variable x is high

The hypothesis is that: If variable X is high; individuals are happier.
This is true in my complete sample

Then the sample was split in 2 (District A and District B)

The hypothesis holds for District A
The hypothesis does not hold for District B (not significant)

I have to interpret these result... I looked at the descriptive statistics of dummy X between District A and District B.

For District A the mean is close to 0.8 and for District B the mean is .04

Is this the reason why my the result for District B is not significant? As in dummy x is hardly present in district B

Answer (score 0):

1) Having exposure prevalence of 0.04 does *not* mean that the association *must* be insignificant. However, reaching significance *will* be difficult (you have little power), as you can only detect strong effects with such small prevalence. But this is just a general explanation, and to find out what is "strong effect" or "rare exposure" in your problem you will have to use your field knowledge or power analysis.

2) Consider what could be the pros/cons of including districts as an interaction term instead of stratifying by them.

3) Keep in mind that the tests do not test the alternative hypothesis (*individuals are happier when X is higher*), so be careful phrasing your results. In particular, saying that the alternative hypothesis does not hold in district B is a gross mistake, if you have no power to detect anything there.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I did find after omitting other variables that variable X becomes significant for District B. Even though the correlation between the variables is quite low (between 0.2 and 0.4), could this mean that the other variables "captures" something in my dummy X? (sorry don't know how to formulate properly what I mean)

Comment: @Jennifer4 Yes, it could be that the association between X and the outcome is confounded by other variables, and including those in the model removes the association. But variables should be chosen prior to analysis. If you are not sure on how to do this, read up on DAGs, confounding, or check out other answers in SE, for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89476/including-confounders-in-a-model